# Preciso de obter a lista de musicas

Tags: java

Eu queria imprimir a lista de músicas guardadas num array `listaMusica`:

```
   System.out.println(p.listarMusicas());
```

Este é o método para guardar os dados:

```
  Musica v = new Musica(t, a, d, ano, g);
                         p.addMusica(v);

 public void addMusica(Musica música) {
    if (_musicas < _capacidade) {
        _listaMusica[_musicas] = música;
        _musicas++;
    }
}
```

E este é o método `listarMusicas()`:

```
   public String listarMusicas() {
    String res = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < _musicas; i++)
        res += i + ": " + _listaMusica[i].getTítulo();
    return res;
}
```

Vou disponibilizar todo o código agora neste link:
http://pastebin.com/4rY6dtab

Aceito sugestões.

Comment: Não entendi. O que você quer fazer? O método listarMusicas() já responde a tua pergunta. Talvez se adicionar um \n depois de getTitulo() fique melhor de ler, mas não sei se é isso o que você quer.

Comment: Por que você não usa `List<Musica>`?

Comment: Quando eu faço isso ele nao mostra realmente a lista de musicas

Comment: Algum pode ajudar-me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código está extremamente difícil de manter, e por isso possui alguns bugs que você deverá resolver (vide abaixo).

Mas para imprimir a lista, sugiro criar um método toString() na classe Música:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Musica [_titulo=" + _titulo + ", _autor=" + _autor
            + ", _duracao=" + _duracao + ", _ano=" + _ano + ", _genero="
            + _genero + "]";
}
```

Assim fica mais fácil de iterar sobre o array.

No método listarMusicas() chame esta lista e use um StringBuilder (que é mais eficiente) para concatenação de Strings:

```
public String listarMusicas() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(Musica m: _listaMusica) {
        if(m!=null) {
            sb.append(m);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Feito isso, o seu código ainda possui alguns problemas que precisam ser corrigidos. Vou listá-los aqui:

- Não use um Array para a lista de músicas. Use uma `List<Musica>`. Esta é a estrutura correta para o seu caso, em que a lista pode crescer e diminuir. Outro motivo é não precisar checar se o elemento é nulo. A List tem o tamanho exato que você precisa, e poderá usar o forEach para iterar sobre ela facilmente.
- Não use a variável `_musicas` para controlar o tamanho do Array (ou da Lista). O Array possui a propriedade length e a List possui um size().
- Ao remover uma música da lista, ele faz `_musicas--`. Só que se remover várias vezes, a variável fica negativa! Isso gera um ArrayOutOfBoundsException. Mais um motivo para não controlar isso por fora.
- Não use variáveis com underscore (_), pois diminui a legibilidade.
- Não use variáveis com acentos e caracteres fora do padrão (`getTítulo`, `getDuração`). Isso vai te facilitar quando abrir o código por outros editores (ou outras pessoas usarem).

Boa sorte no seu trabalho.